# How to consolidate Cloudwatch lambda log groups in a common log group

Tags: amazon-cloudwatchlogs

My app has more than 100 lambdas on AWS as it works on a microservices pattern.
As configured by default, each lambda is writing on his own log group.

I'd like to get a view of the logs accross all my lambdas. I cannot use Logs Insights as I have more than 100 groups to search in.

Do you know how I can create a Log Group that would be an aggregation of all my lambda Log groups ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way, but I ended up creating a Subscription Filter Lambda that copies all the logs to a single log group.

```js
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
var zlib = require("zlib");
var { v4: uuid } = require("uuid");

const cloudwatch = new aws.CloudWatchLogs();

exports.handler = async function (input, context) {
  const now = new Date();
  const LOG_GROUP_NAME = "/aws/lambda/" + process.env.STAGE + "-main";
  const LOG_STREAM_NAME =
    now.getUTCFullYear() + "/" + now.getUTCMonth() + "/" + now.getUTCDay() + "/" + uuid();

  try {
    var zippedInput = new Buffer.from(input.awslogs.data, "base64");
    const unzippedDataBuffer = await unzipLogs(zippedInput);

    var awslogsData = JSON.parse(unzippedDataBuffer);

    await cloudwatch
      .createLogStream({
        logGroupName: LOG_GROUP_NAME,
        logStreamName: LOG_STREAM_NAME,
      })
      .promise();

    await cloudwatch
      .putLogEvents({
        logGroupName: LOG_GROUP_NAME,
        logStreamName: LOG_STREAM_NAME,
        logEvents: awslogsData.logEvents.map((logEvent) => {
          const { id, ...cleanEvent } = logEvent;
          return cleanEvent;
        }),
      })
      .promise();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

async function unzipLogs(zippedInput) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    zlib.gunzip(zippedInput, function (error, buffer) {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
        return;
      }
      resolve(buffer);
    });
  });
}
```